# Overriding Chef default attributes and dependant attributes

Tags: chef-infra

I can override default attributes in my recipes\roles but I am unable to get any other attributes that are dependant on that attribute to also update.

as an example, for the phantomjs cookbook I want to install 1.9.7 rather than the default 1.9.2.  *(I know this change has now been committed to the cookbook repo)*

I can override the version with:

> node.set['phantomjs']['version'] = "1.9.7"

but in the phantomjs default attributes there is a dependant attribute that uses this with string substitution to generate the base url for the download:

> default['phantomjs']['basename'] =
>   "phantomjs-#{node['phantomjs']['version']}-linux-#{node['kernel']['machine']}"

Is there a way to set the version attribute so that the change is performed before these dependant attributes are evaluated? Or a way to force a re-evaluation?

This has been a problem I have hit before and in the past I just override everything that is dependant .. but this is not a great approach going forward.

I am using the latest chef (just tested with 11.8.2 under vagrant but latest chef 11.10.4 elsewhere) and using both chef-solo and the chef server.

Thanks.

Comment: Set it in an attribute file, not a recipe

Comment: thanks sethvargo .. I also tried overriding the value in the attribute file of my cookbook .. I tried default and override and I also tried include_attributes for the attributes of the cookbook I was trying to override.  Still did not affect the dependant attribute.

Comment: Hrm. That seems like a bug, but was definitely fixed in Chef 11...

Comment: @BlueSkies I have the exact same issue with the phantomjs cookbook. My current fix is to re-declare the calculated attributes below my `default["phantomjs"]["version"] = "1.9.7"` definition, but this is obvious not the solution ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your own cookbook (that override this attribute) upper in run list. String interpolation (`foo-"#{whatever}"`) executed in compile time (while loading attribute files) and chef-client loads them in order of run list.

Or you have an option to override all dependent attributes manually, but this is road to hell.

Comment: I have mine higher in the runlist but still I have to manually update all the attributes.